# Excessive Windows Security Event Logs

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging

I'm working on modifying our current Windows log setup and have ran across an issue I can't quite seem to find the answer to. We currently have nxlog configured on each DC to send windows event IDs 4624 and 4625 to a central log server for basic user login information, both successful and failed. The nxlog config works just fine but the issue I have is with excessive logon events.

When testing the config, I logged into a few different machines using my domain credentials. On each test, I received anywhere between 10 - 70 4624 events per login. They were all "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing[524]: An account was successfully logged on.   Logon Type: 3" type of log and always came from the same DC.

Below is a log example that is basically repeated over and over again.

> Dec 17 13:02:57 dc1.domain.com
>   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing[536]: An account was successfully
>   logged on.    Subject:       Security ID:  ________ Account Name: -
>   Account Domain: -       Logon ID:     0x0    Logon Type:  3    New
>   Logon: Security ID:  __________    Account Name:   my_user_name
>   Account Domain: my_domain Logon ID: __________  Logon GUID:
>   {_________}    Process Information: Process
>   ID:   0x0      Process Name: -    Network Information:
>   Workstation Name:     Source Network Address: 192.168.1.10      Source
>   Port:  61371

I want it to tell me that X user is logging in, but I only  need 1 of those entries per login and not multiple ones.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric